# Is there a way to run a script file using a command from inside the neo4j shell?

Tags: neo4j, missing-features

I would like to run a script file by using a command in the shell or power console of neo4j.
Is there a way?

Clarification: it is really the goal of running a script from within the shell.

Something like the *gsh* command for running a groovy script.

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want to run a shell script from inside of neo4j-shell, or do you want to run cypher from say a linux shell *using* neo4j-shell?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Mark Needham's World Cup Dataset GitHub example where he has used the Neo4j shell to run a series of Cypher scripts for data import.

https://github.com/mneedham/neo4j-worldcup/blob/master/doit.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e

if [[ -z "$WC_DB" ]]; then
    echo "Make sure you set \$WC_DB before running this script"
    echo "e.g. export WC_DB=\"/path/to/neo4j-community-2.1.4\""
    exit 1
fi

echo "starting up Neo4j instance at ${WC_DB}"
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j status
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Neo4j not started. Run ${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j start before running this script"   
fi

${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/clear.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/indexes.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/loadMatches.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/loadSquads.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/loadLineUps.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/loadEvents.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/connectAdjacentWorldCups.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/addGeoLocations.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/loadCountryInformation.cyp
${WC_DB}/bin/neo4j-shell --file data/import/addContinents.cyp
```

Making sure that you have exported the system variable `$WC_DB` to contain the path to your running Neo4j instance. You can see that the flag `--file` allows you to pass in a Cypher script as a file to the `neo4j-shell` as an argument.